# Find voice pitch on Android

Tags: java, android, audio, fft

How can I find min, max, mean, std dev pitch from my voice record ?
I use AudioRecord to record my voice.

```
frequency = 8000;
channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

recordInstance = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, bufferSize);
```

After I use FFT algorithm to process voice raw data and get float[]

after I use this function:

```
private float[] spectrumAnalyz(float[] spectr) {
float Re;
float Im;
float[] spectruData = spectr;
float[] mySpectrum = new float[(spectruData.length / 2) - 1];
for (int i = 1, j = 0; i < spectruData.length / 2; i++, j++) {
Re = spectruData[2 * i];
Im = spectruData[2 * i + 1];
mySpectrum[j] = (float) Math.sqrt(Re * Re + Im * Im);
}
return mySpectrum;
}
```

this function return frequency array. after searching at google I found this formula
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_(music)

```
pitch = 69+12*log2(F/440Hz), where F is frequency in Hz.
```

using this formula i can find min, max, mean and std dev pitch.

Are all correct ?

Answer (score 0):

An FFT returns an array of complex magnitudes for a bunch of selected audio spectrum frequency bins.  It does not directly estimate pitch frequency, since musical pitch is not just a spectral frequency bin.

If you do use a pitch detection or estimation method (weighted autocorrelation, cepstrum, RAPT, etc.) the formula you quote will give you a MIDI number for that pitch frequency.

Comment: How can I get frequency data with human voice information ? Maybe I should use some lib or framework?